# performance difference between update_one() and insert_one() in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I've been reading about MongoDB and realize i can insert a new document with insert_one() or with update_one(upsert = True).
since I manage my own ids, it is easier for me to query by a specific id and create the doc if not exist, without the need to handle 2 different methods (create and update).
Queries should be very fast in MongoDB, so what do i trade for this convenience?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you trade nothing. You should use `insert_one()` only for explicit creation of objects.